# Duvida com Incremento + Loop .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, script, javascript-eventos

**Tenho esse script:**

```js
var startValue = '0.00000001', 
    stopPercentage = 0.000001,
    maxWait = 800,
    stopped = false, 
    stopBefore = 1; 

var $loButton = $('#double_your_btc_bet_lo_button'),
    $hiButton = $('#double_your_btc_bet_hi_button');

function multiply(){
    var current = $('#double_your_btc_stake').val();
    var multiply = (current * 1.70).toFixed(8);
    $('#double_your_btc_stake').val(multiply);
}

function getRandomWait(){
    var wait = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxWait ) + 120;
    console.log('Waiting for ' + wait + 'ms before next bet.');
    return wait ;
}

function startGame(){
    console.log('Game started!');
    reset();
    $loButton.trigger('click');
}

function stopGame(){
    console.log('Game will stop soon! Let me finish.');
    stopped = true;
}

function reset(){
    $('#double_your_btc_stake').val(startValue);
}

function deexponentize(number){
    return number * 10000000;
}

function iHaveEnoughMoni(){
    var balance = deexponentize(parseFloat($('#balance').text()));
    var current = deexponentize($('#double_your_btc_stake').val());
    return ((balance)*2/100) * (current*2) > stopPercentage/100;
}

function stopBeforeRedirect(){
    var minutes = parseInt($('title').text());
    if( minutes < stopBefore ){
        console.log('Approaching redirect! Stop the game so we don\'t get redirected while loosing.');
        stopGame();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
$('#double_your_btc_bet_lose').unbind();
$('#double_your_btc_bet_win').unbind();
```

> *Loser*

```js
$('#double_your_btc_bet_lose').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(event){
    if( $(event.currentTarget).is(':contains("lose")') ){
        console.log('You LOST! Multiplying your bet and betting again.');
        multiply();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $loButton.trigger('click');
        }, getRandomWait());
    }
});
```

> *Winner*

```js
$('#double_your_btc_bet_win').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(event){
    if( $(event.currentTarget).is(':contains("win")') ){
        if( stopBeforeRedirect()){
            return;
        }
        if( iHaveEnoughMoni()){
            console.log('You WON! But don\'t be greedy. Restarting!');
            reset();
            if( stopped ){
                stopped = false;
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            console.log('You WON! Betting again');
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            $loButton.trigger('click');
        }, getRandomWait());
    }
});

startGame()
```

**Quero adicionar novas funções a ele como:**

- Um contator de derrota
- Quando perder "x" vezes seguidas (definida pelo operador) usasse a função `multiply();`
- Apos usar esse função e ganhar voltasse com a função `startValue` e entrasse no *loop* novamente.

Tenho mais ou menos a ideia de como fazer mas não sei fazer funcionar 
pois fiz assim na função *Loser*.

```
derrota=0;
$('#double_your_btc_bet_lose').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(event){
        if( $(event.currentTarget).is(':contains("lose")') )
        console.log(derrota + "derrota");
        derrota++;

                setTimeout(function(){
                        $loButton.trigger('click');
                }, getRandomWait());        
                if(derrota >= 10)
                {
                    {
                            console.log('You LOST! Multiplying your bet and betting again.');
                            multiply();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                    $loButton.trigger('click');
                            }, getRandomWait());
                    }
                }
});
```

Porem parece não ser o bastante!